# Unity Hub no me deja instalar una version

Tags: unity

E[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]stoy utilizando la version de unity hub 3.6.1, ahora quiero instalar la versión del editor Unity 2022.3.15f1, pero cuando llega a esta (adjunto imagen) parte me salta este error, la vd ya no se que mas hacer, ya probé todos estos metodos:

-desinstalar e instalar unity
-ubicar bien los archivos y direcciones de descargas
-desinstalar versiones antiguas
-actualizar la licencia
-Tengo espacio de sobra en el disco
-reinicié mi pc
-borré los archivos viejos de residuo de unity
-desactivé mi antivirus

Aclaro que antes no me daba este error, pero desde la primera vez que lo instalé siempre he tenido problemas con los archivos, entonces a cada rato lo tenía que desinstalar e instalar otra vez, espero alguien me pueda ayudar, GARACIAS.....

Como ya dije, probé muchos metodos pero nada me funciona, no me deja pasar de ahí, este es el error: install failed: Validation Failed

Comment: Por lo que veo no hay una sola forma de arreglar el problema. Deberías mostrar los logs. Te dejo algunos links https://www.reddit.com/r/unity/comments/11stzod/how_to_fix_this_in_unity_hubdownload https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76725422/unity-hub-install-failed-validation-failed-message-whenever-i-try-to-install https://discussions.unity.com/t/editor-application-install-failed-validation-failed/247860

Comment: Has probado a ejecutar como administrador el Hub? A veces a Unity se le va la olla con los permisos y eso y hace esas cosas. Si no lo has hecho antes prueba y me dices que tal :)